# Jquery Ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

When I post base64 string over 1.2 mb apache tomcat giving the error: "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect"
When it is under 1.2 mb it works fine, I receive the data at the server side.

Is there size restriction and how am I going to past this issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot :)

```
   $.ajax({ type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/testServer/image',
        data: {imageData : result} ,
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {

        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP specification doesn't impose a specific size limit for posts. They will usually be limited by either the web server or the programming technology used to process the submission.

---

> In httpd.conf add this line
>
> `LimitRequestBody<filesize>`
>
> LimitRequestBody Directive specifies the number of bytes from 0 (meaning unlimited) to >2147483647 (2GB) that are allowed in a request body
>
> For more information,please refer the URL:
>
> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody
>
> Source: [here](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/change-file-size-limit-apache-13874.html)

Comment: Yes that's what I said 'tomcat gives the error: 'The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect' thanks

Comment: Ok thanks :) It helped, but this is for httpd server. What I did was     <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" maxPostSize="0"/> adding maxPostSize="0" to the connector in server.xml file solved it. Thanks

Comment: See [this](http://www.enterprise-architecture.org/documentation/doc-administration/145-post-size-limit) regarding tomcat...

Comment: Glad to hear that you figured it out! :)